# Why is fruit dropping from my apricot tree?

Tags: fruit-trees, fruits, apricots, fruit-drop

Our apricot tree is about 15 years old. The tree bears flowers and then fruits, but as the time passes all the fruit drops from the tree.

Comment: Welcome to the site sadik! We need some more details in order to best help you. Where do you live? How mature do the fruits get before they fall off?  Is this a new problem? Would you please post a picture or two of the tree? Our site is different from others you may have seen. A look around the [help] will help you understand why we're asking these things. [Ask] is a good place to start. We're glad you're here and hope to be able to help you with your tree!

Comment: If it's not pest damage, the tree probably isn't getting enough water

Answer (score 2):

*Our apricot tree* sounds as though the environment could be a residential setting and *The tree bears flowers and then fruits* sounds as though this might be an annual occurrence. Hence an alternative to lack of water, from [Kristi Waterworth](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/apricots/apricot-fruit-falling-off.htm) may be of interest:

> ### Why Apricot Fruits Fall from Tree
>
> Apricot fruit falling off your tree
>   happens because most trees produce significantly more flowers than
>   they need. The odds are that these flowers won’t all be successfully
>   pollinated, so the extras are like insurance for the apricot. In a
>   residential setting where conditions are easier to control, these
>   extra flowers are regularly pollinated and too many fruits set. The
>   stress of so many fruits causes apricot trees to shed fruits -
>   sometimes twice! The main shed comes in June, when small, immature
>   apricot fruits fall from tree, allowing the remaining fruit more space
>   to grow.
>
> ### Managing Apricot Fruit Drop
>
> As with peach thinning, you can hand-thin fruits to prevent them from
>   falling off apricot trees unpredictably. You’ll need a ladder, a
>   bucket and some patience; it can be time consuming, but hand-thinning
>   is a lot easier than trying to clean up the mess after a fruit shed.
>   Remove maturing apricots from branches, leaving two to four inches between
>   remaining fruits. This may feel like dramatic thinning, but the fruits
>   that result will be larger and fleshier than they would have been if
>   they were left alone.
>
> ### Apricot Scab
>
> Although fruit drop is a yearly event for most apricot trees, apricot
>   scab, which also affects peaches, can also cause fruits to drop. This
>   apricot disease leaves fruits covered in tiny, olive-green spots
>   measuring 1/16 to 1/8 inch long. As the fruit expands, the spots do
>   too, eventually merging into dark blotches. These fruits may crack
>   open and drop prematurely. Fruits that ripen fully are often only
>   superficially damaged. Good sanitation, including complete harvest of
>   all fruits and clean-up around the base of the tree during and after
>   fruit ripening, can help destroy the organism. A broad-spectrum
>   fungicide like neem oil can destroy the fungus if applied after
>   harvest and again when buds set in the spring.